# Cannot add default favorites and hotseats to launcher

Tags: android, default, launcher, favorites

I've added

```
<favorite
    launcher:className="com.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery"
    launcher:packageName="com.android.gallery3d"
    launcher:screen="3"
    launcher:x="1"
    launcher:y="3" />
```

in res/xml/default_workspace.xml,but the gallery icon was not added.And when adding hotseats it appears the same problem.
Can anyone help me?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the Samsung device you can create /system/csc folder and copy here file default_workspace.xml.
If CSC.apk is available in the /system/app (or /priv-app) folder, all changes in /system/csc/default_workspace.xml must be applied to default homescreen settings.

Comment: There is a comment in that XML file saying "Update the db with new hotseat items"; Where is this?